# Dynamic Material Icon - Too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running into an issue where I get

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Upon loading the CoursePage.js component. Is there a better way I could implement a dynamically changing button than what I currently have in AddDelete.js?

**backend/models/course.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    fields: Array,
    number: Number,
    name: String,
    minCredits: Number,
    maxCredits: Number,
    description: String,
    isSaved: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

const course = mongoose.model('courses', courseSchema);

export default course;
```

**backend/controllers/course.js**

```
import CourseData from '../models/course.js';

export const getSpecificCourse = async(req, res)=> {
    try {
        const selectedCourse = await CourseData.findOne({ _id: req.query.courseId });
        
        res.status(200).json(selectedCourse);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message});
    }
}
```

**backend/routes/course.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import { getSpecificCourse } from '../controllers/courses.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/courseId', getSpecificCourse);

export default router;
```

**backend/server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import courseRoutes from './routes/courses.js';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/courses', courseRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, {dbName: "dbName"}) // Hidden for privacy
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () =>
        console.log(`Connection is established and running on port: ${PORT}`)
        )).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

**frontend/src/components/CoursePage.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import './styles.css';
import { AddDelete } from './AddDelete';

export function CoursePage() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [course, setCourse] = useState()
  const { courseId } = useParams()

  const url = 'http://localhost:5000/courses/courseId/?courseId=' + courseId;

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then( (selectedCourse) => {
        setCourse(selectedCourse.data);
        setLoading(false);
    } )
  }, [])

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
    
  return (
    <div>
      <AddDelete course={course}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**frontend/src/components/AddDelete.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import FavoriteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import { Button, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import axios from 'axios';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    icon: {
      color: "#0479a8",
      fontSize: "400%"
    }
  });

const changeSaveStatus = (id, trueFalse) => {
    const params =  {
        "id": parseInt(id),
        "bool": trueFalse
    }
    axios.put('http://localhost:5000/saved-courses', params)
}

export function AddDelete(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [courseList, setCourseList] = useState([])
    const [method, changeMethod] = useState(props.course.isSaved);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Button style={{borderRadius: "50%"}} onClick={changeMethod(!props.course.saved)}>
                {method ?  <DeleteIcon className={classes.icon} /> : <FavoriteIcon className={classes.icon} />}
            </Button>
        </div>
        
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try replacing `changeMethod(!props.course.saved)` with an anonymous arrow function `() => changeMethod(!props.course.saved)`. In your case, its getting set during the render itself instead of a button click

```
 return (
        <div>
            <Button style={{borderRadius: "50%"}} onClick={() => changeMethod(!props.course.saved)}>
                {method ?  <DeleteIcon className={classes.icon} /> : <FavoriteIcon className={classes.icon} />}
            </Button>
        </div>
        
    );
```